# when I launch my flutter app I get this error Error: Member not found: 'UnicodeChar int get UnicodeChar => Char.UnicodeChar;

Tags: flutter, dart

whenever I run my flutter I get this error can anyone here help me out

I have upgraded the version and resolved the gradle errors just but on this error i am stucked

Answer (score 0):

Some dependencies may be outdated, try upgrading them.

##### From the Terminal (inside the project's folder):

`flutter pub upgrade`

##### From Visual Studio Code

1. Open **Command Palette...** (<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> on MacOS)
2. Type `Flutter: Upgrade Packages`

##### From Android Studio

1. Open **Search Everywhere** (<kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> on MacOS)
2. Type `Flutter Pub Upgrade`

PS: You may need to run `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions` to resolve major version dependencies constraints